# MacBook Air - random start/wake up times

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, sleep-wake, startup

I have a 3yo MacBook Air running Lion. When I open it to start using it again it seems to sometimes have trouble 'waking up'. Sometimes this is instantaneous, sometimes I get a blank screen for 30 seconds, sometimes the screen is ok but all the programs are frozen and sometimes I can move the mouse around the screen but cant click anything.

All these states seem to sort themselves out after about 2 minutes which isnt too bad - just slightly annoying.

I've also noticed that it doesnt seem to matter how long the laptop has been on standby for or what programs are running in the back ground - It just seems random.

Is this natural? Would anyone know why this is occurring?

Like I said, not a big issue at all - just curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was my hard drive being very close to full.